# "Join as shapes" and the issue of same number of vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices, shape-keys

I would like to morph objects using shape keys (Join as shapes). But it has a very big limitation which almost makes it useless. You can't morph Suzan to be a torus. You can't morph between two words. You need to be very lucky to have two objects with the same number of vertices to be able to use this feature. How can I get around this? Is there an addon or something like that to try to match the number of vertices of the two objects?
Thank you,

Comment: Morphing is a very complicated question, I guess for some cases it's better to switch to a video/fx editor, or morph your object as close as possible, make it invisible and make the other one visible etc

Answer (score 2):

The same number of vertices is not enough, they have to be listed in the same exact way internally, so shape keys have to share the same exact topology of their base shape (edited or sculpted or altered as vertex location only).

An useful trick is to morph both obiects toward a standard object (like a sphere) and use it as "middle" point.